# Are they numbers or dimensions

Tags: xetex, tex-core

I wonder if there is a way to tell if a macro is a number or dimension, as shown in the following example. That is to say, if the macro is number, some thing will be done, if it is a dimension, some other thing will be done.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\begin{document}
\def\aaa{3.5pt}
\def\bbb{\dimexpr 3.5pt}
\def\ccc{\textwidth}
\def\ddd{3.5}
%if \aaa is a number:
%then ...
%else ...
\end{document}
```

I'd like to give another example to describe my intention:

```
\newcommand\test[2]{
  %if #1 is a number
    \parbox{#1\textwidth}{#2}
  %if #1 is a length
    \parbox{#1}{#2}
}
\test{0.5}{some text}
\test(1in}{some text}
```

Comment: Actually, with `\def` (macros), they are neither numbers nor lengths, but merely a string of tokens.  Numbers are typically employed with `\newcount` or `\newcounter` and lengths employ `\newlength`.  Though I suppose my comment is missing the point of your question.

Comment: Thank you.`\def` is a wrong way. I'd like to make my question much clearer.  If there is a string (3.5 or 3.5pt stored in a macro and its content can not be know in advance), how can I refer it as a number or length.

Comment: @lyl A token list can contain other token lists, including code. Is that part of your use-case too? For example, `\documentclass{article}
\tracingmacros=1
\newcommand\test{\testa\testb\testc[c]\testd}
\newcommand{\testa}{0.5}
\newcommand{\testb}{1}
\newcommand{\testc}[1][C]{\ifx C#1\relax cm\else in\fi}
\newcommand{\testd}{}
\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}` produces `0.51in`.

Comment: Usually expansion is not suppressed when TeX gathers tokens belonging to a quantity. Do you wish to detect whether (the result of expanding) a collection of tokens forms a valid TeX-<number>-quantity or <dimen>-quantity as defined in chapter 24 of the TeXbook? A collection of tokens may form an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm. Such an algorithm in turn may, e.g., form an infinite loop. Thus checking if an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm yields whatsoever valid TeX-quantity subsumes checking if the algorithm terminates (error-free) at all. This reminds me of the halting-problem... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I employ something of a trick to distinguish number versus dimension.  Since `\newcount`s can be used to store lengths in machine units, I set `\mytest=\dimexpr#1 pt\relax` in box 0.  If `#1` was a number, then `#1 pt` will be interpreted as a length, and `\mytest` will contain its value in machine units.  However `\box0` will be of zero width, as nothing will have been typeset therein.

If, on the other hand, `#1` is a dimension, then `\mytest=\dimexpr#1 pt\relax` will set `#1` into `\mytest` and the trailing `pt` will be typeset as two letters into `\box0`.

Thus, by examing the width of `\box0`, one can ascertain whether `#1` was a number or dimension.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcount\mytest
\newcommand\testit[1]{%
  \sbox0{\mytest=\dimexpr#1 pt\relax}%
  \ifdim\wd0>0pt dimension\else number\fi
}
\begin{document}
\def\aaa{3.5pt}
\def\bbb{\dimexpr 3.5pt}
\def\ccc{\textwidth}
\def\ddd{3.5}

\testit{\aaa}
\testit{\bbb}
\testit{\ccc}
\testit{\ddd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, `\mytest` could have been defined with `\newlength` rather than `\newcount` with the identical result.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution!. I modified my quesiton.  Would you have a look at it?

Comment: +1 from me. But stupid me tried this while `\nullfont` was in effect. ;-)

Comment: Many thanks! Would you say more about `nullfont` with my example?

Comment: @lyl That was a joke. The test works by probably placing content into a box and checking if the width of the box exceeds 0pt. This works out only as long as a font is in use whose glyphs have some width. `\nullfont`, however, is a font which does not provide glyphs which have a width. That font is used as a means for preventing visible output in situations where you don't want characters typed in the .tex-input-file to yield visible output.

Comment: @UlrichDiez As I've heard quoted among military members, "the [fill in equipment name] will not work in O-F-F mode."

Comment: Thank you @Ulrich Diez Then how to make the output re-visible?

Comment: @lyl You can ensure that the test is run while `\nullfont` is not in effect, but, e.g., `\normalfont` is in effect: ```\newcommand\testit[1]{\begingroup\normalfont\sbox0{\mytest=\dimexpr#1 pt\relax}\expandafter\endgroup\ifdim\wd0>0pt \message{dimension}\else\message{number}\fi}``` This test is suitable for distinguishin a <dimen> from a <number> in case the argument definitely either is a <dimen> or is a <number>. This test is not suitable for 100% reliably detecting whether it is the case that the argument definitely either is a <dimen> or is a <number>.

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX has built in commands to detect whether units are supplied or not so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\test[1]{%
\@defaultunitsset\dimen@{#1}\textwidth
\parbox{\dimen@}}
\makeatother
\fbox{\test{0.5}{some text}}
\fbox{\test{1in}{some text}}
\end{document}
```

if you have an old latex release you will also need to add

```
\def\@defaultunitsset#1#2#3{\@defaultunits#1\dimexpr#2#3\relax\relax\@nnil}
```

after the `\makeatletter`

---

If you want to test and do different actions rather than just default a unit you can make modified versions of the internal command,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\testunits{\afterassignment\test@to@nnil}
\def\test@to@nnil#1\@nnil{\def\zz{#1}}
\def\test#1{%
\testunits\dimen@#1\textwidth\@nnil
\ifx\zz\empty
  \detokenize{#1} is a number
\else
  \detokenize{#1} = \the\dimexpr#1\relax\ is a length
\fi}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\test{5.5}

\test{5.5in}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but not immune to malice. ;-> `\def\IAmBad{0\IAmBad}\test{\IAmBad}{some text}`

Comment: @UlrichDiez `\def\parbox{\parbox}` will not have a good outcome either, tex is tex.

Comment: @David Carlisle fail to run your code in my computer, why?

Comment: @lyl ah you must have an old latex, I added a note to the answer

Comment: And how to use optional args of \parbox in this solution?

Comment: @David Carlisle In this solution, number or dimen is changed to dimen, and ther do the same thing(as the dimen arg of \parbox). However, if the input of number or dimen does differnt things, how to do? For example, if the input is a number, typeset it, if it is a dimen, use it do draw a rule.

Comment: @lyl are you sure you want such an interface??  OK I'll add something that does that

Comment: @David Carlisle
Yes. I intend to get a logical result, which can be used in \ifnumber or \ifdimention(self-set logical token) later.

Comment: @lyl answer updated

Comment: @David Carlisle In this solution, a dimen macro `\textwidth` is used for a input of number. I wonder if there is method to handle both dimention macro and common macro like `\def\aaa{30pt}. If the input is 0.1, then the result is 3pt.

Comment: @lyl in the final test version `\textwidth` isn't really used, any length would do itsvalue isn't used, it is just testing if the parsing for a length stops before that (as it will with 5in or if it is taken as part fo the length. The actual value 5.5\textwidth is not used.

Comment: in the first version you can not use the default length as a macro as it will not do what you want. `3\textwidth` is a valid length 3 times textwidth but if you use `\aaa` instead the code works the same way but  `3\aaa`  is not three times 30pt it is 330pt

Comment: Sorry, I mean the first solution. I try with `\def\aaa{30pt}` and `\aaa` replaces `\textwidth`, I get 0.13pt when the input is `0.1`, not `3pt` (0.1 x 30) that I want.

Comment: @lyl well that is tex syntax I can't do anything about that. `0.1\aaa` and `0.1\textwidth`  are both valid lengths but have very different interpretations.  You have no need for a macro there just use `\newdimen\mydefaultength` and `\mydefaultlength` in the definition then you can use `\mydefaultlength=\aaa` if you want to use `\aaa`

Comment: @lyl This is exactly how the latex picture enviornment works with `\defaultunit` being a length register holding the default length (the internal commands come from there)

Comment: @David Carlisle In your first solution, if I want replace `\textwidth` with `2in`(which may come from an argument of a a macro, #2 for example), how to do? I tried replace `\textwidth` with `\dimexpr 2in` and failed.

Comment: @lyl `\@defaultunitsset\dimen@{#1}{\dimexpr 2in\relax}` worked when I tried it just now.

Comment: `\makeatletter
\def\@defaultunitsset#1#2#3{\@defaultunits#1\dimexpr#2#3\relax\relax\@nnil}
\newcommand\test[3][\textwidth]{%
\@defaultunitsset\dimen@{#2}\dimexpr#1\relax
\expandafter\newdimen\csname #3\endcsname
\csname #3\endcsname\dimen@
}


% Test:
\test{1in}{aaa}\the\aaa\\ 
\test{1}{aaa}\the\aaa\\ %
\test[\parindent]{1}{aaa}\the\aaa\\
\test[\parindent]{1in}{aaa}\the\aaa\\ 
\test[2in]{0.5}{aaa}\the\aaa\\`  I tried this, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: @lyl you havn't braced the third argument, as I showed you want it to be `{\dimexpr 2in\relax}` if it is not just a single token such as `\texwidth` you have just passed in `\dimexpr` as `#3 ` you need `{\dimexpr#1\relax}`

Comment: Oh! That's it! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The test can be done by two nested ifs. The outer `\if` looks like `\if!!` or `\if!pt !`.

```
\def\isnumber#1\iftrue{\if!\unless\ifdim\maxdimen<#1pt \fi!}

\isnumber 13\iftrue It is a number
            \else   It is a dimen
            \fi

\isnumber\hsize \iftrue It is a number
                \else   It is a dimen
                \fi

\bye
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! And, does that mean #1(number or dimen) must be less than 16384? I don't quit unserstand the use of `!`, woud you say more about it?

Comment: The previous solutions assume the #1 less or equal 16384 too because there is setting `\dimen0=#1pt` here. My solution is expandable. If you need to accept #1 bigger then the solution will be much more complicated.